# How was this array built?

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering how this array was built so I can duplicate it:

`a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}`

I was created from a multi-select `<select>` and in this case just one option was selected. This is what it looks like when four are selected:

`a:4:{i:0;s:2:"65";i:1;s:2:"67";i:2;s:2:"68";i:3;s:2:"64";}`

These are entries in the database. I am trying to duplicate the output from another `<select>`

I guess they are just putting the selected options into an array, but I'm not sure how to duplicate it so my output is the same.

Comment: Use `serialize` / `unserialize`

Comment: It's an array that has been [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), if you want to convert it back to an array use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: @Clive when I do that this is the result I get in the database `s:19:"a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}";` what i need is `a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are serialized arrays. You can use the PHP function `serialize()` with an array as argument. For example:

`$serialized = serialize(Array("1", "2", "3"));`

This function is needed to represent arrays as string - if you just use an array as string (for example write it in a database column, if you do not think about correct database modeling), it is just shown the text `Array`. For some purposes you just need an array as string, therefore you can use `serialize` or `json_encode`.

The reverse method for `serialize` is `unserialize`, you have to pass a string and get back an array in this case. Of course, you can use `serialize` and `unserialize` with objects too, then the properties will be serialized.

Comment: when I do that this is the result I get in the database `s:19:"a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}";` what i need is `a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}`

Comment: sorry, when I do `$serialized = serialize(Array($var_name));` the result I get is `s:19:"a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}";` It is setting the array as a string. the result I need is that minus the `s:19:" ";`

Comment: What is the content of `$var_name`?

Comment: @YobdDigital: If I `serialize` the array with the element `54`, I get this: `a:1:{i:0;i:54;}` (https://eval.in/464920). If you serialize the serialized array, you get a serialized string, marked by `s:` at the beginning. You serialize it two times, but you should do that only one time. Just remove one `serialize`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94534/discussion-between-yobd-digital-and-richard-reiber).